# Need help creating a trigger on an opportunity

Tags: trigger

I have two custom fields on the Opportunity object, a text field and a lookup field.  The text field gets populated from an outside source and I want to populate the contents of text field  and have it display in the lookup field.

I need help to create a simple trigger for this on the Opportunity object.

**Opportunity object**
text field - Discount_Code__c
lookup field - Discount_code_LU__c

Basic logic would be "Discount_Code_LU__c = Discount_Code__c"

Comment: you can refer this trailhead to write a trigger and if you face any issues then post with your code.  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro

Comment: Is this discount code a salesforce Id?

Answer (score 0):

Basic premise would be:

```
trigger codeLookup on myObject__c(before insert, before update){
    //If the Discount_Code__c is a unique string value on the code object. Assumes only one record for a given code
    Map<String,Id> codesMap = New Map<String,Id>();
    //

    for(myObject__c o : trigger.new){
        //If Discount_Code__c is a string value - otherwise not needed
        if(!string.isBlank(o.Discount_Code__c) codesMap.put(o.Discount_Code__c,null); //Add code to set to query
        //If Discount_Code__c is an Id
        o.Discount_code_LU__c = o.Discount_Code__c; //If an Id simply set the value
    }

    //If Discount_Code__c is a string value
    for(Codes__c c : [Select ID, codeField__c From Codes__c Where codeField__c In :codesMap.keySet()])
        codesMap.put(c.codeField__c,c.Id); //Add record to map using code as Key (One record per code)
    //

    //If Discount_Code__c is a string value - otherwise not needed
    for(myObject__c o : trigger.new){
        o.Discount_code_LU__c = codesMap.get(o.Discount_Code__c); //Gets Id from Map - Clears value if no record found
    }
    //

}
```

Removing what you do not need and replacing API names with the ones to match your org